# Como entender e começar um serviço rest ou soap

Tags: web-service

Ainda não consigo olhar para um web service e dizer se ele é `REST` ou `SOAP`. A pergunta é:

1. Quando usar um ou outro
2. Como diferenciar ao ver o código se é **REST** ou **SOAP**
3. Performance entre um e outro

Acho às vezes difícil formular perguntas. Bem, então vamos. Cheguei na empresa agora e vi dentro de um projeto, um web service. Lá tem o asmx.cs e o asp.net dele. Esse web service está dentro do projeto. É um projeto aspx e tenho como dever reescrever tudo usando MVC 4 ou 5, no meu caso 5. Bem, aí pensei em manter o web service rodando, mas como ele está junto no mesmo projeto anterior e como terei que reescrever em MVC, terei que recriá-lo dentro do meu atual projeto. Irei reaproveitar quase tudo nele e talvez acrescentar algo novo. Daí a pergunta inicial. Mas gostaria de saber de vocês se tem como pegar esse web service e desmembrar do projeto atual ou isso é utopia pura. Devo realmente reescrever? Essa é também minha dúvida.

Answer (score 5):

Um webservice REST é mais leve do que o SOAP pois a estrutura de trafego de dados é geralmente menor. Isso acontece pois ao usar SOAP a transferência de dados é feita com XML, enquando que um serviço REST normalmente se usa JSON, que é um formato mais simples.

Em termos de facilidade de uso, um webservice SOAP vai ser mais fácil de integrar do que um REST. Isso ocorre pois serviços SOAP funcionam sobre um padrão muito bem definido, que permite a descoberta de serviços, ou seja, apresenta metadados sobre os próprios serviços.

O padrão permite definir de forma clara, os parâmetros e retornos de um método do webservice, e é capaz de trafegar erros... é um verdadeiro padrão de RPC (remote procedure call).

Além disso, o padrão SOAP tem amplo suporte das ferramentas de desenvolvimento. Dessa forma é muito fácil, em um projeto qualquer, usar um webservice baseado em SOAP, pois as ferramentas permitem gerar automaticamente o código para consumir tais serviços, criando métodos e classes de forma automática.

Já um webservice REST, é mais difícil de usar, pois você teria de codificar e decodificar as mensagens por si próprio, além de não haver validação automática do formato da mensage, e nem mesmo existe uma forma de descobrir quais serviços estão disponíveis, portanto terá de saber de antemão quais são eles.

O REST não é um padrão por si só... é apenas um consenso em se utilizar do protocolo HTTP para mensagens de API's, de forma representativa, ou seja, usando os verbos e status HTTP de forma coerente com a especificação. Não existe, por exemplo, obrigatoriedade em se usar JSON.